# bash won't change prompt when executed from zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, python-venv

I use zsh, but we have some scripts that require bash and won't work in zsh. Basically what script does - it sets bunch of env vars and activates python VE. Usually when you activate python VE natively in bash, it changes the prompt:

```
mbp-ag:web-pr
mbp-ag:web-pr ag$ source etc/setup.bash
(ve)mbp-ag:web-pr ag$
```

See those parentheses? Now my problem is, when I run bash from zsh and activate python VE it activates it, but doesn't change the prompt. I don't like that

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question as it stands. Post your `.bashrc`, your `.zshrc`, the script in question, and any other relevant script. Though I will hazard a guess: maybe you're exporting `PS1` or `PROMPT` — in which case, don't: these are shell variables, not environment variables; they have different meanings in different shells.

Comment: I think zsh when starts, sets some ENVs, that preventing bash to change the prompt when pyenv activated.

Comment: I've figured out... zsh with antigen and plugins handles prompt, that's why it sets `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1`. I have to unset it in bash profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out... zsh with antigen and plugins handles prompt for pyenvs, 
it sets `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1`. Once I unset that in bash profile, it works

Answer (score 0):

There's a mention here of someone with the same problem as you. Their solution was to edit the  `PS1` shell variable in the `bin/activate` file:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87062/how-to-display-the-name-of-the-current-virtualenv

There's also this ZSH plugin for virtualenv: https://github.com/tonyseek/oh-my-zsh-virtualenv-prompt

Quote:

> It support to customize the virtualenv prompt in oh-my-zsh themes.

Comment: Wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Gilles, Edited my answer. Why would it work in a native bash environment, but not in a subprocess of ZSH?

Comment: My problem is not in zsh... zsh prompt displays VE (if activated) properly. bash doesn't

Answer (score -1):

the prompt is a variable assigned to "PS1" so do something like

```
PS1="{new prompt}"
```

for example:

```
-bash-4.1$ PS1=">"
>
```

Comment: The whole story is a lot more complex than that, and anyway you aren't answering the question, which is about getting the python VE startup script to set `PS1` automatically.